# How to generate a thumbnail from videos without load the whole video?

Tags: video, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

There are so many ways to generate a thumbnail from a video, but I am wondering do they need to load the whole video?

As far as I can think, if I just want to extract the first frame in video and convert it into an image, it is no need to load the whole video.

But I also know that not every video format is stream-like. So is there a general way to generate a thumbnail from a video with the least cost?

PS: OS is linux and I want to use command line.

Comment: Look into FFmpeg since it's most useful as command line tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video), example from the docs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

This example will seek to the position of 0h:0m:14sec:435msec and output one frame (-vframes 1) from that position into a PNG file.

Comment: To help others, the fastest way described in documentation is `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:14.435 -i input.flv -vframes 1 out.png`. It will seek the frame with keyframe without decode all frames. Instead, the command you give will decode from start to this frame.